# Why does my variable resets it's value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I am making a small Python console RPG. I have a very basic fighting system in place, but the health values of my `player` and `enemy` keep resetting after they've taken damage. Any ideas as to why this is happening? I think it might have something to do with my variables not being `global` or not being declared properly, but I can't find the mistake (I don't really understand how global variables works in Python). I did some testing ( as you can see by the `# Testing` comments), and the `attack()` function does take the health away but when it returns to the `fight()` function the health is back to 100% for both variables.

```
import sys
import os
import random

def clear(): return os.system('clear')

# Program
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = 100
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.attack = 5
        self.health_stat = "{}/{}".format(self.health, self.max_health)

class Goblin:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = 50
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.attack = 2
        self.health_stat = "{}/{}".format(self.health, self.max_health)
goblin = Goblin("Goblin")

# all other enemies are the same as the Goblin

enemies = [wolf, goblin, rat, bandit]

# New game
def start0():
    global player
    player = Player('Mark')
    start1()

def start1():
    clear()
    print("Name: {}\n"
          "Health: {}\n"
          "".format(player.name, player.health_stat,))

    print(".1) Fight\n"
          ".4) Exit\n")

    selection = input("-> ")
    if selection == "1":
        select_enemy_to_fight()
        fight()
    elif selection == "4":
        sys.exit()

def select_enemy_to_fight():
    global enemy
    enemy = random.choice(enemies)

# Actions
def attack():
    clear()
    playerAttack = random.randint(0, player.attack)
    enemyAttack = random.randint(0, enemy.attack)

#player attack
    if playerAttack == 0:
        print("You miss!")
    else:
        enemy.health -= playerAttack

        print("You dealt {} damage!".format(playerAttack))
# Testing
        print("PH = ", player.health)
        print("EH = ", enemy.health)
    input(" ")

    if enemy.health <= 0:
        win()

    clear()

# Enemy attack
    if enemyAttack == 0:
        print("The enemy missed!")
    else:
        player.health -= enemyAttack
        print("The enemy dealt {} damage!".format(enemyAttack))
# Testing
        print("PH = ", player.health)
        print("EH = ", enemy.health)
    input(" ")
    # clear()

    dead() if player.health <= 0 else fight()

def fight():
    global enemy
    global player
    clear()

    print("{}   vs   {}".format(player.name, enemy.name))
    print("{}'s Health: {}  {}'s Health: {}".format(player.name, player.health_stat, enemy.name, enemy.health_stat))

    print(".1) Attack\n"
          ".3) Run Away\n")

    selection = input("-> ")
    if selection == "1":
        attack()
    elif selection == "3":
        run()

main()
```

Comment: I would recommend to create a `Game` singleton object, convert your variables as class variables, and convert your functions as class methods. At this point of your game, it can be very quick. Global variables are evil.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah tell me about it... Any idea where I went wrong though?

Comment: @StefanPochmann most of it are spaces and simple assignments, not too meaty I promise.

Comment: No, sounds fine to me (except for the design!) but I have a motto: when a supposedly simple thing fails for a strange reason, it is likely to happen again, and you're clearly using a wrong pattern. If you really want to suffer, I propose you keep it this way.

Comment: You're more likely to get help with this if you can create a [mcve] that focuses on your problem.

Comment: @lokil Still I highly doubt that it is [**minimal**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Not going to even *start* reading so much code.

Comment: I think converting it to `Game` singleton would work right away no need to investigate. Design with global variables is bad, period. No need to fix a broken program.

Comment: The first thing to tidy up is the duplicate code - why not have a class character that takes a name and max_health as initialisation values - this can then be expanded to have an attack strength defence strength, etc. Likewise once you have failed to run you should call fight - the rule is whenever you could copy and paste abstract and generalise instead.

Comment: The `attack` function changes `player.health` but doesn't update `player.health_stat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = 100
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.attack = 5
        self.health_stat = "{}/{}".format(self.health, self.max_health)
```

`self.health_stat` is using the original `self.health`, so after `self.health` changes `self.health_stat` remains the same.

I made this solution:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.max_health = 100
        self.health = self.max_health
        self.attack = 5
    def health_stat(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.health, self.max_health)
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try mark the variables global in `attack` function, as you d in `fight` and see?